# A fragment container for tabbed views

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-viewpager, fragmentmanager

I'm currently doing a huge UI/UX refactor on my App. I used to have a tabbed view which handled a ViewPager with several fragments on my main Activity.

The thing is that now one of those tabs is going to contain a ViewPager as well, and I don't really trust a the view pager to handle that level of fragment nesting.

So I'm trying to find a container to replace the Activity's ViewPager. My first approach was just using the FragmentManager, and set and remove the fragments as the user tapped on the tabs. But I'm a little worried that this could bring issues in the future. And I don't really like having fragment references on memory.

My next approach is declaring the Fragments in the Activity's layout inside a FrameLayout and bring the to front when the user taps on a tab. But yet again, I'm worried that this could bring issues in the future.

So my question is; What approach should I take here? I stick with the ViewPager, even if one of the Fragments has a ViewPager inside as well? I use the FragmentManager approach? The FrameLayout approach? Is there an alternative fragment container that isn't the ViewPager and can manage the Fragments state?

I think that this is a pretty straightforward question so I didn't include any code. But If you feel confused about what I'm asking, please leave a comment and I'll add some examples.